# ORA-00911: invalid character xsql error

Tags: sql, oracle, character, ora-00911, xsql

I m using sql query in the xsql file but I have ORA-00911: invalid character error. Same query is working directly on the database.

My index.xsql:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2" ?>
<page connection="labor" xmlns:xsql="urn:oracle-xsql">
    <xsql:query>
            SELECT id, iata_dep, iata_arr FROM route JOIN flight ON route.route_id=flight.route_id
    </xsql:query>
</page>
```

My browser result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2" ?>
<page connection="labor" xmlns:xsql="urn:oracle-xsql">
    <xsql:query>
            SELECT id, iata_dep, iata_arr FROM route JOIN flight ON route.route_id=flight.route_id
    </xsql:query>
</page>
```

Where is the character problem?
Thanks,

Comment: "SELECT * FROM flight" is working without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems that can cause such behavior :

- > This error occurs when you try to use a special character in a SQL
  >   statement. If a special character other than $, _, and # is used in
  >   the name of a column or table, the name must be enclosed in double
  >   quotations.
- > This error may occur if you've pasted your SQL into your editor from
  >   another program. Sometimes there are non-printable characters that may
  >   be present. In this case, you should try retyping your SQL statement
  >   and then re-execute it.
- > This error occurs when a special character is used in a SQL WHERE
  >   clause and the value is not enclosed in single quotations.

Comment: I followed that but problem is same.

Comment: Why would either of those cause an ORA-00911?